# how to countdown to a date

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if anyone can help me. After hours of searching tirelessly on here and the web I can't seem to find a simple countdown using jquery. I don't want to use any sort of plugin just a simple jquery code to countdown from a date. I have managed to find this code below. But even with this code placing it in my website nothing appears. I added the jquery file from jquery.com and added the proper divs with `counter` ID and nothing. If anyone can explain or show me how to make a simple countdown in a function that takes in a date format and returns a countdown I would appreciate the help.

```
var end = new Date('02/19/2012 10:1 AM');

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

Comment: your DIV needs the id "countdown", not "counter".

Comment: @Gregor that was a typing mistake its "counter"

Comment: Can you tell me the same question u asked, with dynamic date. U are here giving hardcode date, I want dynamic date

Answer (score 142, accepted):

This is working fine as a normal javascript.

```
<script>
var end = new Date('02/19/2012 10:1 AM');

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
</script>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Your output is appearing as follows:-

### 1days 9hrs 3mins 22secs

### UPDATE

## Using Functions:

```
<script>

    CountDownTimer('02/19/2012 10:1 AM', 'countdown');
    CountDownTimer('02/20/2012 10:1 AM', 'newcountdown');

    function CountDownTimer(dt, id)
    {
        var end = new Date(dt);

        var _second = 1000;
        var _minute = _second * 60;
        var _hour = _minute * 60;
        var _day = _hour * 24;
        var timer;

        function showRemaining() {
            var now = new Date();
            var distance = end - now;
            if (distance < 0) {

                clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

                return;
            }
            var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + 'days ';
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
        }

        timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
    }

</script>
<div id="countdown"></div>
<div id="newcountdown"></div>
```

Output will appear as follows:-

### 0days 23hrs 25mins 8secs

### 1days 23hrs 25mins 8secs

Comment: @bammab: No change, I did. Just placed the javascript under **<script>** tag and **<div>** as outside..

Comment: thank you. if i could bother you with one thing. can you tell me how to make this into a function so that I may have 2 counters running at the same time?

Comment: @HungryDB So that you will be able to stop the timer and clean up resources, I believe

Comment: @Siva - Can you tell me the same question u asked, with dynamic date. U are here giving hardcode date, I want dynamic date, and countdown should reset and start on evry morning 11 am

Comment: @Khushbu_sipl: You are looking for an answer which is different from the posted question. Kindly open a new question and show what you have tried so far to help you better.

Comment: How can this solution be extended such that the when the days, hours, minutes and seconds go into single digits - they become 01days, 05hours, 08minutes, 09seconds?

Answer (score 11):

That's not jQuery, that's JavaScript. But anyways...

You almost got it. The only issue is `var distance = end-now;`. It should be:

```
var distance = end.getTime()-now.getTime();
```

Also, you shouldn't use `+=` on `innerHTML`. Instead, use a variable (example: `var output = ""`) and add to that, then assign to the `innerHTML` at the end.

Finally, double-check that the ID of the `div` matches the ID you have in `getElementById`.

Comment: I'm really starting to hate the trend of people referring to javascript as jQuery... it's like people think you couldn't do anything with js before jquery came along.

Comment: @Kolink yeah this doesnt seem like very good code. do you know of any place i can find a jquery solution?

Comment: Where *end* and *now* are Dates, then `end - now` and `end.getTime() - now.getTime()` will produce identical results since `-` will coerce the Dates to Number anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my contribution for the sake of new readers of this post.

I am using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` so that we can easily update the target date while it is still counting down. I will also include the time of the target day for a better precision and the time will be local. So i guess this covers most of the possible requirements to start with.

```js
function refreshTimer(){
  function countDown(){
    setTimeout(function(now){
                 var dif = (td-now)/1000,
                      ss = Math.floor(dif % 60).toString().padStart(2,"0"),
                      ms = Math.floor(dif/60 % 60).toString().padStart(2,"0"),
                      hs = Math.floor(dif/3600 % 24).toString().padStart(2,"0"),
                      ds = Math.floor(dif/86400).toString().padStart(3,"0");
                  remainingTime.textContent = dif > 0 ? `${ds} Days ${hs}:${ms}:${ss}`
                                                      : "Sorry. You are already late..!";
                  active && countDown();
                  this.removeEventListener("change", kill); // possibly redundant
                }, 1000, Date.now());
  }
  var td     = new Date(this.value),
      active = true,
      kill   = _ => active = false;
  this.addEventListener("change", kill);
  countDown();
}

var targetDateTime = document.getElementById("targetDateTime"),
    remainingTime  = document.getElementById("remainingTime");

targetDateTime.addEventListener("change",refreshTimer);
```

```html
<input id="targetDateTime" type="datetime-local">
<p id="remainingTime"></p>
```

It would be ideal to have the days, hours, minutes and seconds in their own `<div>`s or `<span>`s for a better display in which case updating them individually would be another task.