# Countdown keeps changing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, countdown, countdowntimer

Right, basically I have a countdown timer that doesn't do exactly what it says on the tin.

The PHP outputs correctly, but once it's echo'd within the Javascript, the date constantly changes.

I will load the page, and it will show one ETA, and I'll refresh and it could jump forward an hour or jump back several hours?

I just need the timer to countdown to the 20th March 2015.

The PHP Code

```
<?php 
  $futureDate = '2015-03-20';
  $d = new DateTime($futureDate);
?>
```

The Javascript

```
    $('#counter').countdown({

        timestamp : (new Date()).getTime() + <?php echo $d->diff(new DateTime())->format('%a*%h*%i*%s*1000'); ?> 
});
```

Here's a Live Preview

[Preview](http://jakeord.com/modelface/)

Please, somebody help lol

Comment: use `getDays` instead of `getTime()`, since you're converting to days in microseconds.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `futureDate - presentDate` ? Or just `futureDate`, without adding anything, depending on what you do with it?

Comment: What's the significance of all this math? `timestamp: (new Date()).getTime() + 22*2*10*55*1000`

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this in javascript

[how to countdown to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335140/how-to-countdown-to-a-date)

```
var end = new Date('03/20/2015 0:0 AM');

var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var timer;

function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0) {

        clearInterval(timer);
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

        return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = days + 'days ';
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
}

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your javascript with

```
$('#counter').countdown({
        timestamp : new Date('2015/03/20') 
});
```

As it is now you're overcomplicating things - you just need to set the date of the countdown to when you want it to finish.