# How to Countdown to a day using Android CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android, xml, countdown, countdowntimer

I'm new here and new to Android Development, I Have a question regarding the Android CountDownTimer. How am I able to use Android's CountDownTimer, to count down to a specific date, let's say the 6th Novemeber 2015? Also How would I use the Java code with corresponding XML Code?

I had a llok at this question ([how to countdown to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335140/how-to-countdown-to-a-date)) and couldn't really understand what was going on? Can anyone spare a moment to help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is exactly how you do it

**UPDATE 3**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    TextView tv_countdown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);

    Calendar start_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar end_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    long start_millis = start_calendar.getTimeInMillis(); //get the start time in milliseconds
    long end_millis = end_calendar.getTimeInMillis(); //get the end time in milliseconds
    long total_millis = (end_millis - start_millis); //total time in milliseconds
    end_calendar.set(2015, 10, 6); // 10 = November, month start at 0 = January

    //1000 = 1 second interval
    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(total_millis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);

            long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);

            long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);

            long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished);

            tv_countdown.setText(days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds); //You can compute the millisUntilFinished on hours/minutes/seconds
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            tv_countdown.setText("Finish!");
        }
    };
    cdt.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks NaviRamyle That's helped me a lot, How and what do I link this too in XML for it to appear in a textView on screen? Also How do I add Hours, Minutes and Seconds?

Comment: Here `TextView tv_countdown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.you_textview_id_from_xml);`

Comment: Please look again at my answer, I edited a few things

Comment: Thanks, how do I add hours minutes and seconds?

Comment: I added the lines of codes to compute for the hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: I modified the computation of the hours i removed the ` % 24`

Comment: Thanks again, one last question what do i need to add to include days?

Comment: Would I just need to add this long days   = (long) (millisUntilFinished / (1000*60*60*60));

Comment: I simplified the computation, please check. Also don't forget to upvote :)

Comment: Thanks again, in android studio 'end_calendar.set' the '.set' attribute is in red along with '.start' of 'cdt.start'

Comment: cannot resolve symbol 'set' also cannot resole symbol 'start'

Comment: put it all inside the onCreate() method

Answer (score 1):

```
Date currentDate=new Date();
Date endDate=new Date();
long difference = endDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
new CountDownTimer(difference, 1000)     {

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

}

public void onFinish() {
  System.out.println("Done");
 }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Helpful method !**

```
@Override
public void start(final long miliSecond, final int interval) {

    new CountDownTimer(miliSecond, interval) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long day = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(day);

            long hour = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hour);

            long minute = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minute);

            long second = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished);

            intDay.setText("" + day);
            intHour.setText("" + hour);
            intMinute.setText("" + minute);
            intSecond.setText("" + second);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // What ever you want !
        }

    }.start();

}
```