# Display days, hours... that have past since a date in Android (Chronometer)

Tags: java, android

I have made a Countdown to a future date (with remaining days, hours, minutes, seconds) using CountDownTimer and lots of code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32773716/3984944
Now I want to do exactly the same but counting up from a past date. My TextView should refresh every second and show the elapsed time.

**What I tried:**
I tried manipulating the CountDownTimer so that it works in reverse order. Changing the interval to -1000 or adding 2000 milliseconds to the Countdown every second. Both didn't work.
Then I figured I should use the Chronometer class. The standard Chronometer only displays hours, minutes and seconds as far as I'm concerned. So no days. I then wrote the following code in the style of the CountDownTimer answer I found before that updates a TextView with the desired data:

```
    final Chronometer ch = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.ch_chronometer);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_show_stopwatch);

    ch.setBase(endMillis); //endMillis is the date in Milliseconds

    chCountdownSince.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer cArg) {
            long t = System.currentTimeMillis() - chCountdownSince.getBase();

            long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(t);
            t -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);

            long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(t);
            t -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);

            long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(t);
            t -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);

            long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(t);
            String stopwatchDisplay = "Days: %d Hours: %d Minutes: %d Seconds: %d";
            stopwatchDisplay = String.format(stopwatchDisplay, days, hours, minutes, seconds);
            tv.setText(stopwatchDisplay);
        }
    });
```

I feel like this snipped makes absolute sense but upon execution it doesn't change my TextView at all. I feel like this is just not how Chronometer works but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit :

### I think you forgot to start Chronometer completely.

[Given that](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#onTick(long))

> The calls to onTick(long) are synchronized to this object so that one
>   call to onTick(long) won't ever occur before the previous callback is
>   complete.

Its unlikely that ticks are done on UI thread, but this is exactly where you need to set your text, try changing

```
tv.setText(stopwatchDisplay);
```

to

```
tv.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        tv.setText(stopwatchDisplay);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to make any difference. Also I had to change the String to final btw

Comment: have you checked under debugger and/or with logs that you get any ticks at all?

Comment: it doesn't enter the "onChronometerTick" method at all. Any idea why it isn't entering?

Comment: I don't see you calling start on Chronometer

Comment: Well...I feel really stupid now..but YES it works now! Thank you! (You should write that as an answer and I'll accept it as the solution)

Comment: I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

please use handler..

```
public void countDownStart() {
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
            try {
                FestCountdownTimer timer = new FestCountdownTimer(00, 00, 9, 3, 01, 2017);
                new CountDownTimer(timer.getIntervalMillis(), 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                        int days = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 86400);
                        int hours = (int) (((millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                                - (days * 86400)) / 3600);
                        int minutes = (int) (((millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                                - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
                        int seconds = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60);
                        String countdown = String.format("%02dd %02dh %02dm %02ds", days,
                                hours, minutes, seconds);
                        txtTimerDay.setText("" + String.format("%02d", days));
                        txtTimerHour.setText("" + String.format("%02d", hours));
                        txtTimerMinute.setText(""
                                + String.format("%02d", minutes));
                        txtTimerSecond.setText(""
                                + String.format("%02d", seconds));
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        textViewGone();
                MainActivity.aSwitch.setChecked(false);
        creditText.setText("Toggle On To Start");
                    }
                }.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1 * 1000);

}
```

Remember, `9 is Hours,3 is date,1 is Febraury Month`..Month starts from `0th Index`

FestCountdownTimer class

```
public class FestCountdownTimer {
    private long intervalMillis;
    public FestCountdownTimer(int second, int minute, int hour, int monthDay, int month, int year) {
        Time futureTime = new Time();
        // Set date to future time
        futureTime.set(second, minute, hour, monthDay, month, year);
        futureTime.normalize(true);
        long futureMillis = futureTime.toMillis(true);
        Time timeNow = new Time();
        // Set date to current time
        timeNow.setToNow();
        timeNow.normalize(true);
        long nowMillis = timeNow.toMillis(true);
        // Subtract current milliseconds time from future milliseconds time to retrieve interval
        intervalMillis = futureMillis - nowMillis;
    }
    public long getIntervalMillis() {
        return intervalMillis;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks! Isn't Time() deprecated? I would like to avoid that.

Comment: I got it running setting the Timer to a date in the past(since that is what I want) and setting the `timer.getIntervalMillis()` to the negative number. It shows me the correct time but the seconds and minutes are sort of "twitching". The longer the timer runs the worst it gets. After a while the seconds are unreadable because they change the value 50 times a second.