# Creating simple countdowns in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, timer, countdown

I've been trying to make a few javascript based countdowns/timers to place around my web site... an example of this would be...

"I’m a 25-year-old part-time blogger & designer and full-time waitress & bartender!" where the "25" would increase every year to update the age.

another example would be...

"with my soon to be husband (COUNTDOWN TILL WEDDING HERE)" and change "soon to be husband" to "husband"

ive seen a few script round but not quite what i need..

I've been trying to use the Math.floor method which works for the amount of days but i need to figure out how to add years. is there a way to calculate years using math.floor?

sidenote * i am not very familiar with javascript or anything of the sort whatsoever

Comment: How did you try it and what was the problem?

Comment: What technologies are you using? Is this a static HTML page, or are the pages generated dynamically?

Comment: [Here for the age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-given-the-birth-date-in-the-format-yyyymmdd) and [here for countdown to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335140/how-to-countdown-to-a-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to do that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to My Page!</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="about-me"></div>

</body>

<script>

function get_message() {
    var my_birthday = new Date("2/13/1996"); // update your birthday here
    var today = new Date();
    var time_diff = Math.abs(today.getTime() - my_birthday.getTime()); // get the difference in milliseconds between today's date and your birthday
    var my_age = Math.floor(time_diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365)); // get your age

    var s = document.getElementById('about-me');
    var message = "I’m a " + my_age.toString() + "-year-old part-time blogger & designer and full-time waitress & bartender!";
    s.innerHTML = message; // update your age
   }

window.onload = get_message; // load script only when page is loaded
</script>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This makes sense but how would I input it into a page, such as an about me page.  Nothing shows when I try to add it

Comment: @tsukinoakari Save the above code as "something.html" if you are writing the web page from scratch. How are you creating the web page? A website builder?

Comment: im creating the page from scratch