# javascript counter script just skips to 0

Tags: javascript

I'm making a website that projects how many seconds left until Christmas. I made some of it, but I don't know a lot of javascript. It does work a little bit, but it just skips to zero and not one at a time. The thing is, I have no idea how to do it. I have searched and found about a function called setTimeout but when I use it, it just doesn't load and just crashes.

any help is needed

```js
function counter(timeLeft) {

    while (timeLeft > 0) {
        timeLeft = timeLeft - 1;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".time").text(timeLeft);
        });
        return;
    }

}

counter(1500);
```

Comment: make no sense to have the document ready inside the loop. Second the while loop is going to run until it is zero. It is not going to be rendering every number. If you want to do a count down timer, this approach is wrong. You want to use setTimeout or setInterval

Comment: Third, `return` exits the function, and with that the while loop, regardless of `timeLeft`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335140/how-to-countdown-to-a-date

Comment: setInterval worked so thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the document ready event listener and get rid of the return statement. There really is no point in the return statement in the above code.

Comment: It still skips to zero, I appreciate you trying to help though.